# Why can't I perform a std::copy on a vector of std::shared_ptr's in C++0x?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've written a path class in my program for handling heirarchical path structures.  I decided to use std::shared_ptr as the standard return type for the whole class since I'm getting rather fond it.

What surprised me is that I was unable to use std::copy or the normal vector.insert(v.begin(), v.end()) to copy elements to/from vectors of shared_ptr.  Why is this?

```
shared_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<bfile>>> butils::bfile::search()
{
    shared_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<bfile>>> ret(new vector<shared_ptr<bfile>>());
    shared_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<bfile>>> children = getChildren();

    //WTF why don't either of these work?
    //std::copy(children->begin(), children->end(), back_inserter(ret));
    //ret->insert(children->begin(), children->end());

    //I've had to resort to doing this....
    for (auto c = children->begin(); c != children->end(); c++)
    {
        ret->push_back(*c);
        auto cChildren = (*c)->search();
        for (auto cc = cChildren->begin(); cc != cChildren->end(); cc ++)
        {
            ret->push_back(*cc);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

When I tried the std::copy() I got:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\include\iterator(21): error C2039: 'const_reference' : is not a
>   member of 'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>'
>   1>          with 1>          [ 1>
>   _Ty=std::vector>
>   1>          ] 1>
>   BFile.cpp(329) : see reference to
>   class template instantiation
>   'std::back_insert_iterator<_Container>'
>   being compiled 1>          with 1>
>   [ 1>
>   _Container=std::tr1::shared_ptr>>
>   1>          ]

When I tried the insert(v.begin(), v.end()) I got;

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xmemory(208): error C2664: 'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>::shared_ptr(std::nullptr_t)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>' to 'std::nullptr_t'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=butils::bfile
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<std::tr1::shared_ptr<butils::bfile>,std::allocator<std::tr1::shared_ptr<butils::bfile>>>
1>          ]
```

I'm not sure I understand either of these compiler errors... Anyone else have a clue?

Comment: don't get too fond of `shared_ptr`, prefer using `unique_ptr` whenever there is no "shared" ownership. Shared ownership is a concept of its own, and should not be abused for the sake of *ease* as it carries its own woes (cycles of references) which can only be detected by memory leak tools... by experienced programmers.

Comment: @Matthieu - I take your point although given that the objects in question here are just path objects with a string and a bit of state in them it's difficult to see how they could result in a cycle of references.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to make a `back_inserter` to the pointer to the vector, rather than the vector itself. Change `back_inserter(ret)` to `back_inserter(*ret)` (if you really feel the need to dynamically allocate vectors like that).

`insert` is failing because you're missing an argument:

```
ret->insert(ret->begin(), children->begin(), children->end());
```

The bizarre error message there is because there is a 2-argument overload of `insert`, with the second argument being an object to insert. The compiler tries to use this, but fails to convert the iterator into the object type.

Answer (score 2):

`std::back_inserter` expects a sequence, not a `std::shared_ptr`. Use `back_inserter(*ret)`.

For the second, `insert()` requires a third parameter here: `insert(where_to_insert,start,end)`

Comment: insert(0,start,end) didn,t seem to work but I think you had the right idea:  I guess you meant: ret->insert(ret->begin(), children->begin(), children->end());    That did work, thanks!

Comment: Yes - sorry, forgot shortly that we're talking about iterators, not indices. Edited.

Comment: yeah, I think he meant `ret->begin()`.  See reference here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/insert/

Answer (score 0):

consider using a std::transform in place of std::copy.

```
std::transform(children->begin(), 
               children->end(), 
               back_inserter(ret),
               [](const bfile& in) { return make_shared<bfile>(in); });
```